# Swift Dictionary Absurd Memory Usage

Tags: ios, swift, macos, performance, dictionary

I ran into an interesting problem in one of my applications. When accessing a `Dictionary` many times, the memory usage of my application skyrockets to over a gigabyte in seconds. Here is some sample code to show the problem.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        let dictionary = ["key1":"value1"]
        let nsKey: NSString = "key1"
        let swiftKey = nsKey as String
        for _ in 0 ... 10000000 {
            dictionary[swiftKey]
        }
    }
```

Repeatedly accessing the dictionary causes memory to climb until the loop finishes. I looked at instruments and saw tons of string allocations. Turns out using an NSString is the issue.

Changing the nsKey to a swift `String` like so fixes the issue:

```
let nsKey = "key1"
```

Also changing the dictionary to an NSDictionary fixes the issue:

```
let dictionary: NSDictionary = ["key1":"value1"]
```

**Does anyone know why accessing the dictionary using a casted NSString causes so much heap allocation, and are there any other fixes besides the ones described above?**

---

Here are some pictures. It looks like behind-the-scenes strings are being allocated and set to *autorelease* (or am I reading the data below wrong?) Could this be why memory usage continuously allocates and then drains at a later point? If this is true, should this be considered a "bug"? This issue occurs on OS X as well as iOS.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best solution is to not bridge to `NSString` here. Just use Swift types. Or, as you discovered, you can just use Foundation types (`NSString` and `NSDictionary`). Bridging can require making temporary copies.

In any case, though, in loops like this it's very common to create temporary copies for one reason or another (even if you avoided this particular problem). To address that, you need to drain your autorelease pool in the loop. For instance:

```
let dictionary = ["key1":"value1"]
let nsKey: NSString = "key1"
let swiftKey = nsKey as String
for _ in 0 ... 10000000 {
    autoreleasepool {         // <=== the scope of the current pool
        dictionary[swiftKey]
    }
}
```

Adding that will keep your memory steady. This is a very common thing to do in large loops in Cocoa. Otherwise the pool won't be drained until you return from your top-level method.

Comment: Great recommendation of the autorelease pool! I have been sticking with swift types but unfortunately in my real app some of my swift strings were being treated as NSStrings internally, I'm guessing because some external libraries are returning bridged strings. I tried casting and I tried initializing String(myNSString) but still the issue persisted. I probably could have copied the the string byte-by-byte and built a true Swift String that way but that seemed excessive. But this autorelease pool fix is perfect. Do you think it is worth reporting this as a performance "bug"?

Comment: Unlikely worth reporting. Almost any real-world loop of this size should be wrapped in an autoreleasepool. Over time, I expect the cost of bridging to improve and it to become less common in any case. You're correct that in some cases you currently can't practically avoid bridged strings, and generally should avoid trying (you'll just overcomplicate things). But you should avoid adding NSString gratuitously (which I see people do sometimes).

Comment: @RobNapier, I tried Epic Byte code without the autorelease block in real device and I am not experience high memory usage . I find high memory usage issue only in simulator , can you please explain why the behavior is different.

Comment: My guess would be optimization level, but it could be a lot of things. Differences in the compiler between the platforms; difference in Foundation. But in the end it would be some difference in how things are optimized.

Comment: @RobNapier Hey I apologize for this late question, This approach to using an autorelease pool only works if the underlying code uses autorelease instead of release, correct? In other words the autorelease pool would have had no effect if Apple chose to release the string immediately rather than using autorelease? Is this correct? Thanks!

Comment: @EpicByte correct. But if it were released and it were temporary, then it already would have been deallocated and out of memory. The point of an autoreleasepool block is to send a release to pending temporary objects and get them out of memory.