# Swift dictionary memory leak

Tags: swift, memory, memory-leaks

I have a code for an iOS app (Xcode 8.1, Swift 3.0) where AppDelegate creates an object TopHandler, which in-turn instantiates another object WeatherHandler. WeatherHandler periodically executes a rest API call to fetch weather information from a server, parses the returned JSON and adds the parsed fields to a dictionary object (class object). This dictionary object is periodically read by TopHandler and sent to the GUI (as part of another dictionary) via NSNotification.

Every time a new weather information is received, the parse function is called, which updates the dictionary object with the new values.

When looking at Instruments, I see that there is a memory leak in the parse function where the dictionary fields are updated. If I comment the lines that update the dictionary, the leak disappears. However, if I keep that code but comment the NSNotification being posted by TopHandler, the leak is  still there. Any idea what could be happening?

I even tried clearing the dictionary completely before parsing the new JSON but that didn't help either. Code snippets are below. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
TopHandler:

var myWeatherHandler: WeatherHandler!
func initSetup() {
        myWeatherHandler = WeatherHandler()
}

WeatherHandler:
var prevWeatherReportDict: Dictionary<String, String> = ["valid": "N"]

...

func handleWeatherData(_ data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) {
    // Make sure we get an OK response
    guard let realResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
        realResponse.statusCode == 200 else {
            prevWeatherReportDict["valid"] = "N"
            return
    }

    // Read the JSON
    if let weatherReport = NSString(data:data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) {
        parseWeatherReport(weatherReport, updatePrevReport: true)
    }
}
```

....

```
func parseWeatherReport(_ report: NSString, updatePrevReport: Bool) -> String {
    …. // outer level JSON parsing…

    if let code = observation[“code”] as? Int {

        // THESE TWO LINES CAUSE THE LEAK… Commenting these fixes the leak
            prevWeatherReportDict["valid"] = "Y"
            prevWeatherReportDict[“code”] = “\(code)”
        }

    // … more parsing
}
```

Comment: The app crashes intermittently and that made me investigate memory leaks. Instruments shows this as a leak, about 48 bytes per call, so it keeps incrementing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understand that it is tiny but I have multiple such recurring leaks and it adds up, may be not to a point that would crash the app but I still would like to get rid of them, besides understanding why this is causing a leak in the first place.

Comment: I found this post that talks about leaks when accessing a dictionary in a loop but the solution proposed here did not make any difference in my case  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35564653/swift-dictionary-absurd-memory-usage